# How to install oracle instantclient on a custom Jenkins Agent

Tags: oracle, jenkins

I am struggeling to install an oracle driver and use it in my Jenkins builds.
My goal is this:

I would like to run cypress e2e tests in a jenkins pipe. Cypress should be able to execute oracle statements to prepare the database for some tests.

Therefore I created a script with the npm package 'oracledb'. This is working fine on my windows machine.

But in the Jenkins pipe, I can not download the needed instantclient driver files.
So I started to create my own jenkins agent. This agent is a Docker Image which is created from 'FROM cypress/browsers:node14.17.0-chrome91-ff89'. And it is then downloading and unzipping the instantclient drivers.

So far so good, but when I execute a Task on that created agent. I can not find or use the driver that the agent should provide.

So my question is: How can I provide a instantclient installation on an Jenkins agent to be used in executions?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM cypress/browsers:node14.17.0-chrome91-ff89

USER root
ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
ENV LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
RUN mkdir -p /home/jenkins && \
    chown -R 1001:0 /home/jenkins && \
    chmod -R g+w /home/jenkins
RUN ls /home -all

RUN mkdir -p /opt/oracle && \
    chown -R 1001:0 /opt/oracle && \
    chmod -R g+w /opt/oracle
WORKDIR /opt/oracle
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libaio1 wget unzip
RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && rm -f instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    ls  && \
    ls /opt && \
    ls /opt/oracle && \
    cd /opt/oracle/instantclient* && rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *mql1* *ipc1* *jar uidrvci genezi adrci && \
    echo /opt/oracle/instantclient* > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf && ldconfig

RUN chmod -R a+rwX /opt/oracle

RUN mkdir -p /srv/install
WORKDIR /srv/install

COPY buster_addons/ca-certificates-java_20190405_all.deb /srv/install/ca-certificates-java_20190405_all.deb
COPY buster_addons/fonts-dejavu-extra_2.37-1_all.deb /srv/install/fonts-dejavu-extra_2.37-1_all.deb
COPY buster_addons/java-common_0.71_all.deb /srv/install/java-common_0.71_all.deb
COPY buster_addons/libpcsclite1_1.8.24-1_amd64.deb /srv/install/libpcsclite1_1.8.24-1_amd64.deb
COPY buster_addons/libatk-wrapper-java_0.38.0-1_all.deb /srv/install/libatk-wrapper-java_0.38.0-1_all.deb
COPY buster_addons/libatk-wrapper-java_0.33.3-22_all.deb /srv/install/libatk-wrapper-java_0.33.3-22_all.deb
COPY buster_addons/libatk-wrapper-java-jni_0.33.3-22_amd64.deb /srv/install/libatk-wrapper-java-jni_0.33.3-22_amd64.deb
COPY buster_addons/openjdk-11-jre_11.0.7+10-3_deb10u1_amd64.deb /srv/install/openjdk-11-jre_11.0.7+10-3_deb10u1_amd64.deb
COPY buster_addons/openjdk-11-jdk_11.0.7+10-3_deb10u1_amd64.deb /srv/install/openjdk-11-jdk_11.0.7+10-3_deb10u1_amd64.deb
COPY buster_addons/openjdk-11-jre-headless_11.0.7+10-3_deb10u1_amd64.deb /srv/install/openjdk-11-jre-headless_11.0.7+10-3_deb10u1_amd64.deb
COPY buster_addons/openjdk-11-jdk-headless_11.0.7+10-3_deb10u1_amd64.deb /srv/install/openjdk-11-jdk-headless_11.0.7+10-3_deb10u1_amd64.deb

RUN dpkg -i /srv/install/java-common_0.71_all.deb && \
    dpkg -i /srv/install/libpcsclite1_1.8.24-1_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i --force-all /srv/install/openjdk-11-jre-headless_11.0.7+10-3_deb10u1_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i /srv/install/ca-certificates-java_20190405_all.deb && \
    dpkg -i /srv/install/libatk-wrapper-java_0.38.0-1_all.deb && \
    dpkg -i /srv/install/openjdk-11-jre_11.0.7+10-3_deb10u1_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i /srv/install/libatk-wrapper-java-jni_0.33.3-22_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i /srv/install/libatk-wrapper-java_0.33.3-22_all.deb && \
    dpkg -i /srv/install/fonts-dejavu-extra_2.37-1_all.deb  && \
    dpkg -i /srv/install/openjdk-11-jdk-headless_11.0.7+10-3_deb10u1_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i /srv/install/openjdk-11-jdk_11.0.7+10-3_deb10u1_amd64.deb

COPY run-jnlp-client /usr/local/bin/run-jnlp-client
COPY generate_container_user /usr/local/bin/generate_container_user

RUN chmod a+rwx /usr/local/bin/run-jnlp-client && \
    chmod a+rwx /usr/local/bin/generate_container_user

WORKDIR /e2e

# The user who is starting the docker container is not root, but temporary npm data is stored in root!
RUN chmod -R a+rwX /e2e
RUN mkdir -p /tmp && \
    chown -R 1001:0 /tmp

RUN ls /tmp -all

# Run the Jenkins JNLP client
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/run-jnlp-client"]
```

The JNLP stuff is from here: https://github.com/openshift/jenkins/blob/master/slave-base/contrib/bin/run-jnlp-client